# Does instanceof work for commonly imported classes?

Tags: node.js

### The Problem

I am importing a class in two related projects. It appears that the prototype chain of a class instance created in one project does not match the version of the class in the other project.

Specifically, `instanceof` returns false.

### The Code

I have three npm packages / projects (names invented for simplicity):

- `classes` (contains `Payload`)
- `processors` (contains `ProcessPayload`); depends on `classes`
- `main` (not actually a package); depends on `classes` and `processors`

The `main` project creates a `Payload` and passes it to a `ProcessPayload` object.

To be clear: these projects have three separate `package.json` and any associations between them are done via `dependencies`.

**main/index.js**

```
import { Payload } from 'classes'
import { PayloadProcessor } from 'processors'

const payload = new Payload()
const processor = new PayloadProcessor()
console.log(payload instanceof Payload) // true
processor.process(payload)
```

The `ProcessPayload` object imports `Payload` and uses it to validate the type of its parameters.

**processors/PayloadProcessor.js**

```
import { Payload } from 'classes'

class PayloadProcessor {
  process = (obj) => {
    console.log(obj instanceof Payload) // false
  } 
}

export default PayloadProcessor
```

### The Question

What is going on with the prototype chains here.  I plan to use [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and create an `isPayload` method to solve my problem, but are there really two versions of `Payload` floating around in my dependency stack?  Is there any way to get `instanceof` to work as expected in this situation?

Comment: Weird - what does `console.log(obj.__proto__)` print inside `process`?

Comment: `console.log(obj.__proto__)` outputs `Payload {}` (both from `process` and from `main`)